# Copying the entire object in memory

Tags: java

I have this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyClass {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    public MyClass(){

    }

    public MyClass(MyClass aClass){
        this.list = aClass.getList();
    }

    public void add(int number){
        list.add(number);
    }

    public void set(int number){
        list.set(0, number);
    }

    public int get(){
        return (Integer)list.get(0);
    }

    public ArrayList getList(){
        return list;
    }
}



MyClass aName = new MyClass();
aName.add(5);
System.out.println("aName: "+aName.get());

MyClass aName2 = new MyClass(aName);
System.out.println("aName2: "+aName2.get());

aName2.set(1);
System.out.println("aName2: "+aName2.get());
System.out.println("aName: "+aName.get());
```

This will print:
aName: 5
aName2: 5
aName2: 1
aName: 1

I don't want my second object changing the values in my first object.
Is there any way to stop this happening but still be able to copy properties from another object?

Comment: You need to make a copy of the internal ArrayList, not just assign the reference. e.g. `this.list = aClass.getList().clone()`

Comment: Why exactly are you homerolling your own arraylist?

Comment: @wug he isn't, it's creating behavior around an array list.

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  He's homerolling a stack with an arraylist.  Does inserting to the beginning of an arraylist operate in O(N) time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then don't pass the List from the original object to the new object, in

```
public MyClass(MyClass aClass){ 
    this.list = aClass.getList(); 
}
```

It makes both object have a reference to the same list (there is only one list shared between both objects).

You should do

```
public MyClass(MyClass aClass){ 
    this.list = (List) aClass.getList().clone(); 
}
```

Comment: Check whether it is necessary to cast, since clone() returns Object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can stop this. You need to make **defensive copy** of the list in your copy constructor.

```
public MyClass(MyClass aClass){
    this.list = new ArrayList(aClass.getList());
}
```

You could use `clone()`, but as Josh Bloch states in Effective Java item "copy constructors have many advantages over `clone`" - they're preferable in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You could clone() or take a copy, but since you have created a list already, rather than discarding it you could use it. ;)

```
public MyClass(MyClass aClass){
    this.list.addAll(aClass.getList());
}
```

Comment: That's true, he's creating one on declaration. Another reason why `final` variables are useful - that would have detected this bug on compile!

Answer (score 0):

You're copying the *reference value* of the `ArrayList` into your new object. You now have two references to the same list.

You need to create a new `ArrayList` when you construct your second object:

```
public MyClass(MyClass aClass){
    this.list = new ArrayList(aClass.getList());
}
```

Be aware, however, that both lists now contain the *same objects*. Again, this only creates a new list and copies the reference values of the objects inside the original list. If you needed two complete and separate lists containing unique objects you would need to write a method that did a deep copy, duplicating the objects in the list as well.